# How do I handle the event from the TextBox clear icon in GWT?

Tags: gwt

I have a GWT TextBox acting as a filter that responds instantly to an text added to it or removed from it. My problem is the little x at the end of the TextBox in IE10 that clears all of the text from the TextBox. I have yet to find what event is fired and how to capture it like I am with the KeyUp or Blur handler.

Using the onBrowserEvent I can see a MouseUp event come through, but the MouseUpHandler never gets triggered. Even putting the code I want triggered directly in the onBrowserEvent call does nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The click on the X triggers a 'input' event.

So one way to catch it is to sink the input event to the textbox and overwrite the `onBrowserEvent`.

```
TextBox box = new TextBox(){
    @Override
    public void onBrowserEvent(Event event)
    {
        super.onBrowserEvent(event);
        if("input".equals(event.getType()))
            do something
    }
};
box.sinkBitlessEvent("input");
```

Comment: I like the solution, but I'm getting the error "Trying to sink unknown event type input". Is this event handled in newer versions of GWT? I'm on 2.5.1.

Comment: Got it working with 2.6.1. I tried going straight to 2.7, but my eclipse is not recognizing its version. Either way, solution found. Thanks Andreas!